# Typescript getter/setter property array returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my component I have an array called `data` and I need to set value in different parts. I added a new array parameter in `@Input` called `additionalValues`. Now I need to concat values in new parameters with passed `value` to `data`. This was my code:

```
protected data: any[];
protected additionalValues: any[];
```

I changed my code in this way:

```
private _data: any[] = [];

get data(): any[] {
    return this._data;
}
set data(value) {
    this._data = value;

    if (this.additionalValues != null && this.additionalValues.length > 0) {
        this._data = [...this.additionalValues, ...value];
    }
}
```

Where's the problem? When I try to get value from `data` I get the size of array instead of values and, when I use the `find` method, I'll get an error:

```
this.data.find(x => ...);
```

I tried to print value of `_data` array in getter method and it's ok. I also tried to print `_data` at the and of setter method but it's always ok.

Comment: could you show us the code where your are setting the data variable ?

Comment: @Z.Bolbol I usualy set values in this way: `this.data = this.clone(this.allData);`. In clone I simply do this: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`. Private property `_data` it's ok when `data` is wrong

Comment: What is `this.allData` you mentioned above? It isn't in your code snippet in the question

Comment: The code you posted works fine. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's a copy of data from server. But it's not important in this case because when I call `this.data` my private property `_data` have correct values. In getter I simply do `return data;`. If I print `console.debug("DATA: ", this.data, this._data)` I'll see `12 Array(12)[]`

Comment: @AaronBeall This is all. I assign values how you can see in my comment. Maybe is an issue with my psycho Angular/Typescript version...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only missing thing is just to to update your data content when the additionalValues input changes :

```
ngOnChanges(){
    this.data = [] ;
  }
```

Or wait until the next setter call to get the data updated.